# How to get scanner to read pipe delimited txt file in java

Tags: java, pipe, java.util.scanner, jfilechooser, csv

I've been trying to get a scanner to read and sort a pipe delimited text file using delimiter \|but i cant seem to get it to sort or display the reformatted file. When I open the filechooser it also throws and error when i try to import the scanner. The data in the txt file will be a mixture of strings and ints

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("/n");
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[|\n]"));
JTable JT = new Jtable();
List<Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
File readFile;     //creates file variable     
JFileChooser jFileChooser_Open = new JFileChooser();
    int option = jFileChooser_Open.showOpenDialog(this);
    readFile = jFileChooser_Open.getSelectedFile();//instantiates file and 
gets selected file from jfilechooser
     String line;
    try (FileReader inStream = new FileReader(readFile); BufferedReader 
   inBuffer = new BufferedReader(inStream)) {
        //create variable line

            while ((line = inBuffer.readLine()) != -1 ) {
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
List.add(line);
List.add(scanner.nextInt());

}
System.out.println(List);

        }
    }   catch (IOException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
```

Also I want to get the newly formatted string to be displayed in my table or a text area. But if you guys could help me get it to print to the console, then I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: First, when asking a question about an exception, always include the *full stack trace* in your question.  Second, a String is never equal to an Integer, so `((line = inBuffer.readLine()) != -1)` always evaluates to true;  you probably meant `((line = inBuffer.readLine()) != null)`.  Third, always make sure your calls to the hasNext\* and next\* methods of a Scanner match.  Do not mix hasNext with nextInt.  Instead, use `hasNextInt` and `nextInt`.